# Angular2 object property typed as "number" changes to string

Tags: object, angular, typescript, typing, typescript-typings

I have a very simple Angular2 app running locally. I'm using a service to send an instance of an object to a webservice API. The API validates JSON against a schema, and ID's must be numbers (i.e. NOT quoted in the JSON).

My problem is that when I try to send the object to the webservice, my ID field has quotes around it, even though it's typed to be a number in Typescript.

The behaviour is only observed when the `name`property of the object contains "special characters".

I've tested and found that it doesn't seem to be the JSON.stringify I use — please see code below.

The app is written in Typescript.

**Unit class:**

```
export class Unit {
    id: number;   // This is the problem child
    name: string; // This is the string that can contain special characters
    short: string;
    triggers_plural: number;
    is_headline: boolean;
}
```

**Method to save:**

My code for saving an instance of `Unit` to the webservice:

```
updateUnit(unit: Unit): Promise<Unit>
{
    var objSend = {unit_data: [unit]};          // Webservice expects an array of units

    console.log(objSend.unit_data[0].id === 2); // Yields false when ID is 2
    console.log(objToReturn);                   // Logs ID to verify it is 2 when testing

    // Code for actual request
    return this.http.put(`${this.unitUrl}/${unit.id}`, JSON.stringify(objSend),{headers:this.headers})
    .toPromise()
    .then(()=> unit)
    .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

When running the code and calling the method, the console will log that the ID is NOT equal when the `Unit` object's `name` property contains special characters.

Example without special characters (no problem, id is a number):

[image]

Example WITH special characters (eek! Id is a string!):

[image]

The `updateUnit` method is called from my unit-detail component where you can edit a unit:

```
export class UnitDetailComponent implements OnInit {
    unit: Unit; // this.unit later on

    constructor(
        private unitService: UnitService,
        private route: ActivatedRoute
    ){}

    ngOnInit(): void
    {
        this.route.params.forEach((params: Params) => {
            let id = +params['id']; // The routing will give id to look for
            this.unitService.getUnit(id)
            .then(unit => this.unit = unit); // Here the unit is instanciated in the first place
        });
    }

    save(): void
    {
        this.unitService.updateUnit(this.unit).then(this.goBack); // Here is the call to updateUnit method
    }
}
```

It's bound to an input in the template:

```
<div *ngIf="unit">
    <div>
        <label>Edit unit</label>
        <div>
          <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="unit.name" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" (click)="save()">Save</button>
</div>
```

Maybe the problem arises already when the two-way data binding is filling in the `name` property when you write something in the `<input>` but I don't understand how the type of the `id` can change?

Link to github repos of the whole project: https://github.com/djoike/ng2-cookbook/tree/master-so

Comment: Interesting Bug, where does unit_data come from? Is it already a string when updateUnit is called?

Comment: On the line you mention, I'm simply creating an object (objSend) with a property "unit_data", and so It's not existing anywhere before on that line.

Comment: but `unit` (the argument) comes from somewhere right? ...

Comment: Yes, it's passed into the function on the line above: updateUnit(unit: Unit)

Comment: So the big question is what does console.log(unit.id) say? is it a string there already? if so the bug is somewhere else, but not in this function

Comment: If I log the id directly, the console will write 2 in either case, because you can't directly see from the console log output if it's writing numbers or strings — this is why I logged "id === 2" so I'm sure it's checking the type to be a number as well. If you look at the examples you can see it's true for one case and false for the other.

Comment: Ok, but that means the error is where the unit object is originally actually created and not within the function you gave us so where is updateUnit called?

Comment: Updated with information about the source of `unit` var.

Comment: Again, i think the cause is deeper in the UnitService class :-)

Comment: Added link to github repos so you could look into it, if you want. https://github.com/djoike/ng2-cookbook/tree/master-so

Comment: https://github.com/djoike/ng2-cookbook/blob/master-so/app/services/unit.service.ts#L28 

Can you check whether or not your backend introduces those quotes in the json response?

Comment: All right, after checking the web-api outside of Angular, I can confirm that you are indeed correct. It's returning the data with quotes on the id! It's really weird that Angular allows this, since the `unit` class is typed? That might have it's reasons though... Thank you very much for your help! I wonder how I should "close" this question? Posting an answer? Maybe you could post your answer and I can pick it?

Answer (score 1):

A small solution is to cast the field to `any` , and then convert it to a `number` using `parseInt()`, I faced a similar problem just today

for more info about casting, check the **Type assertions** section [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html)